# How to Scroll down with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

In [this](https://signup.insly.com/signup) page, I need to click on the link ***Privacy Policy*** ,(it opens a new dialog),and I must scroll **down**, using Selenium, and Java.

Here is what i have tried:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

it does not work. **It scrolls the background page instead of the active dialog.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the *link* with the text **Privacy Policy** you simply need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*, then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and then *scroll in to view* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class insly_Privacy_Policy {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://signup.insly.com/signup");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("privacy policy"))).click();
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//div[@id='document-content']//following::div[contains(.,'Revision')]"))));
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: revision]

Comment: thanks for the response, let me digest your answer, and i will update my question.

Comment: for sure, i will add the link here, to make sure you see my new question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986601/how-to-scroll-down-in-a-dialog-box-using-selenium

Comment: @DebanjanB do you have any solution for mobile browser scrolling ? I've tried may solution but it's not working.

Comment: @AlImran If you can raise a designated question on _mobile browser scrolling_ in our community, of-coarse the contributors can help you out.

Comment: @KamyarParastesh I have re-read your question and I feel I should help you to understand that if you don't have a validation point, it won't be useful to make _Selenium_ perform any steps e.g. _scrolling_, etc. In your question as you mentioned about _...need to click on the link Privacy Policy ,(it opens a new dialog),and I must scroll down..._ which I feel I should have _closed as too broad_ rather answering. Somehow I stoped at _I need to click on the link Privacy Policy_ and assumed you want to click on the _CheckBox_. Hence answered. I have updated my answer as per your complete steps.

Answer (score 2):

The `div` you want to scroll has a unique id and you need to get a reference to it first:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id('document-content'));
```

Afterwards you can get the last child within that privacy policy div:

```
List<WebElement> children = element.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
assertTrue(children.size() > 0);
WebElement elementToScrollTo = children.get(children.size()-1);
```

You may now be able to scroll to `elementToScrollTo`.

Comment: +1, but you can simplify code as `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='document-content']/*[last()]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);`

Comment: @KamyarParastesh , also make sure that you've added a wait for modal window to appear `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("document-content")))`

Comment: @Andersson please find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986601/how-to-scroll-down-in-a-dialog-box-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to a location relative to the number of pixels in the plane:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```