# How to scroll down in a dialog box using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

In [this](https://signup.insly.com/signup) page, 
The form includes 2 validations regarding the  ***Privacy Policy*** part:

1. Click on the link of *Privacy Policy*, it opens a dialog box and user should scroll it down.
2. Check the checkbox related to it

I have no problem in checking the checkbox, ***but i am not able scroll down*** in the below window:

[image]

I have this method to wait till the elements get loaded:

```
public void waitForElement(String xPath) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xPath)));
    }
```

So, how can i scroll down, and close the window?
I also don't know how should i use my `waitForElement` in this case?

Here is [the repo](https://github.com/salman-/AutomatedSignUp), it is a very short code. You just need to run the `feature` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code to scroll modal dialog down:

```
// Wait for modal
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("document-content")));
// Select last child of content div
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='document-content']/*[last()]")); 
// Scroll to last child node
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```